# From interaction Lagrangian density to scattering amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, neutrinos, scattering-cross-section

I'm currently working on coherent elastic neutrino nucleus scattering (CE$\nu$NS) and have been trying to find out how to obtain the cross section mentioned in all the papers. Unfortunately, it is impossible to find a rigorous derivation of this cross section.

I have a paper that does the following.
They start from an effective interaction
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{NC} = \frac{G_F}{\sqrt{2}} J_\mathrm{NC}^\mu J_{\mathrm{NC}\mu}
\end{equation}
and then state that therefore the amplitude is
\begin{equation}
i\mathcal{M}(\nu + N \rightarrow \nu + N) = -i\sqrt{2}G_F \langle N(k_2)| J_\mathrm{NC}^\mu|N(p_2)\rangle \langle \nu(k_1)| J_{\mathrm{NC}\mu}|\nu(p_1)\rangle.
\end{equation}
The authors don't give any steps in between. [Here is a link to the arXiv paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04150) This derivation can be found in appendix A.

**How can I get to this result?**

Comment: Have you heard of the born approximation??

Comment: @Prahar Yes, but I don't see how that would apply here.